# What is wrong with my expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have this JSON encoded string:

```
[{"id":"23","name":"Louis"},{"id":"24","name":"Lucya"}]
```

I use this in a `$.ajax` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "res/main.php",
    data: { command : "loadPeople" },
    success: function( people ){
          for(var i = 0; i<= people.length; i++){
              var tableRow = '<tr><td>' + people[i]['id'] + '</td><td>' + people[i]['name'] + '</td><td style="text-align: right;"><img src="res/img/b_drop.png" width="16" height="16" id="delete_' + people[i]['id'] + '" alt="" onclick="deletePeople('+people[i]['id']+');"/></td></tr>';
              $("#people").append(tableRow);
          } 
    }
});
```

When I am in my page in Google Chrome with the console opened, I get the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What is wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 8):

As it says `people[i]` is undefined.

I assume you're going out of range because of the test : `<= people.length` should use `<` instead.

Try :

```
for(var i = 0, max = people.length; i < max; ++i) {
```

- Accessing a property is a bit more expensive (depending on how it is coded it may involve a string comparaison). Storing its value in a variable can be faster.
- `++i` is faster than `i++`.

Comment: even better, use `$.each`.

Comment: Yeah but $.each involves a function call for each element (i.E allocating references, copying index, etc) and creating an anonymous function when it can be done with a simple for loop.

Comment: As it says in the link you gave : " The hello world books of programming always start you off with i++, however did you know that i++ comes with a bit of overhead? that's because before you can increment i under the hood a new copy of i must be created. Using ++i you don't need that extra copy. i++ will return the current value before incrementing i. ++i returns the incremented version i. This test is to demonstrate that it's faster to use ++i. Get ready get set update your code! ". The test you did may not have showed you the difference, but it still is true.

Comment: Besides, ++i or i++ are both very fast instructions. The other instructions done in the loop (the boolean test to continue for example) are not negligible and have an influence on the test results. You would certainly notice a bigger difference if you were performing 10000 times the test outside of a loop.

Comment: @Virus721: you pay too much attention to the mythical "performance". Actually, micro-optimizations like `for` vs. `forEach`, let alone `i++` vs `++i` make absolute no sense in everyday javascript programming.

Comment: Here is a more accurate test : http://jsperf.com/i-vs-i-true-test
Of course it is just a detail, but this is even truer in compiled languages where there is no browser doing dozens of instructions you don't know about for a simple ++i. Besides, learning to use ++i instead of i++ costs nothing and isn't less intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem cn be that length because one time more than your array length
Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "res/main.php",
    data: { command : "loadPeople" },
    success: function( people ){
          for(var i = 0; i<= people.length-1; i++){
              var tableRow = '<tr><td>' + people[i]['id'] + '</td><td>' + people[i]['name'] + '</td><td style="text-align: right;"><img src="res/img/b_drop.png" width="16" height="16" id="delete_' + people[i]['id'] + '" alt="" onclick="deletePeople('+people[i]['id']+');"/></td></tr>';
              $("#people").append(tableRow);
          } 
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
for(var i = 0; i< people.length; i++){

}
```

The problem if in your json you don't assign the id you can check if this value is undefined or not:

```
if(people[i]['id']!= undefined){
  //code
}
```

Comment: This way adds an extra adition and an extra boolean test every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your success function like this (before for loop):

```
people = $.parseJSON(people);
```

Comment: it will do that automatically if `dataType` is set to `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

Guess problem is here

```
for(var i = 0; i<= people.length; i++){

      }
```

Array index out of bound.